# In the non-English versions of Star Wars, does Yoda switch words around

Tags: star-wars

I don't know whether this is an appropriate Sci-fi question.  In the English version, Yoda switches the words round and speaks English with an almost German syntax.  Does he also switch the words round in the non-English versions?

Does he speak normally in the German version?

Comment: Awesome question! I'd assume so, it's probably not that difficult

Comment: Ah poo same reddit link, nice spot @jwodder

Comment: Here's an [example of German](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wy25hUXljP4)

Comment: Yes, I think @jwodder 's link answers the question.